# What configuration will my app try and use?

Tags: c#, web-services

Ive got an app with...

```
    [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.ServiceModel", "4.0.0.0")]
    public partial class SearchServiceClient : System.ServiceModel.ClientBase<Bi.Flight.BiSearchServiceFacade.BiSearchService.ISearchService>, Bi.Flight.BiSearchServiceFacade.BiSearchService.ISearchService {

        public SearchServiceClient() {
        }

        public SearchServiceClient(string endpointConfigurationName) : 
                base(endpointConfigurationName) {
        }
```

I have some client code that is calling the parameterless constructor. I have 2 questions...

1) Is this the normal way of calling a REST based service? Because I thought channel factories would be better.
2) When the parameterless constructor gets called does that mean that it will try and pick the endpoing up from configuration? If so what will it look for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) A channel factory *is* being used (inherited from the ServiceModel.ClientBase)

2) Yes, it will pick up the endpoint info from the `<system.serviceModel><client><endpoint />` section in your web/app.config